# Avoid Git conflict

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

Let's admit I want to work on a doc document with 2 parts, and I want to work on these 2 parts with 2 different branches *part1* and *part2*, created from *master*.

When I merge part1 into master, nothing wrong but then, when I merge part2 into master, I have conflicts.

Is there a way to avoid that kind of conflict? If not should I just resolve conflicts, or are there good practices to avoid them?

Comment: Don't be afraid of git conflicts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git-repository)

Comment: "doc" document, as in word? Use word compare function (I know it exists, don't know how it fare) .

Comment: Best practice is to try to avoid editing the same part of a file from multiple places at the same time.